# Find Root doesn't work properly

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-integration

I use a FindRoot that doesn't find the right solution in some range, the FindRoot is the following:

```
tabexp = ParallelTable[{Temp,V /.FindRoot[Ifix - Isis[V/2, 0.2, Temp, 1.5, 1.4, \[Gamma]0, \[Gamma]0,RSISIS], {V, 4.05 d0Al[1.5]/q, 1. d0Al[1.5]/q,4.1 d0Al[1.5]/q}, AccuracyGoal -> 25,  PrecisionGoal -> 25,MaxIterations -> 2000]}, {Temp, 0.2, 1.25, 0.9/40}];
```

This is the plot of the FindRoot output tabexp:

[image]

The point is that the graphical solution is easy:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[{Ifix -Isis[V/2 d0Al[1.5]/q, 0.2, Tx, 1.5, 1.4,[Gamma]0, \[Gamma]0,RSISIS]}, {Tx, 0.6, 0.8, 0.05}]], {V, 1 , 4.3},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I don't understand why it's not working properly.
If you need all the code it is the following:

```
q = 1.602176487` 10^-19;
kB = 1.3806504` 10^-23;
\[HBar] = 1.054571628251774` 10^-34;
TcAluminio = 1.55;
d0Al[TcAl_] := 1.764 kB TcAl;
d0max = 1.764 kB 1.65;
delta[T_] := Tanh[1.74 Sqrt[1/T - 1]];
\[CapitalDelta]Al[T_, TcAl_] := delta[T/TcAl] d0Al[TcAl];

ngammaAl[energy_, T_, gamma_, TcAl_] := 
  Abs[Re[(energy + I gamma d0Al[TcAl])/
    Sqrt[(energy + I gamma d0Al[TcAl])^2 - \[CapitalDelta]Al[T, 
      TcAl]^2]]];
Isis[V_, T1_, T2_, TcAlP_, TcAlI_, gamma1_, gamma2_, Rjunction_] := 
  Re[1/(    q Rjunction)
     NIntegrate[
     ngammaAl[energy - q V, T1, gamma1, TcAlP] ngammaAl[energy, T2, 
       gamma2, 
       TcAlI] (1/(Exp[(energy - q V)/(kB T1)] + 1) - 1/(
        Exp[energy/(kB T2)] + 
         1)), {energy, -10 d0max, -\[CapitalDelta]Al[T1, 
        TcAlP], \[CapitalDelta]Al[T2, TcAlI], \[CapitalDelta]Al[T2, 
       TcAlI], \[CapitalDelta]Al[T1, TcAlP], 10 d0max}, 
     MinRecursion -> 4, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
       "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 5]];
\[Gamma]0 = 10^-3;
RSISIS = 55000;
Ifix = Isis[0.0006/2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.5, 1.4, \[Gamma]0, \[Gamma]0, 
  RSISIS]
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Probably not a good sign when I evaluate your code and it spews a notebook's worth of error messages at me.

Comment: Maybe you're right, and the problem is related to the warning. However I always work like this. The plot doesn't generate any errors, they all come from the find root. In particular, the option ''oscillatory'' seems to generate many warnings, although it usually gives the best result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`V_?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999) removes some errors.  `WorkingPrecision -> 32` removes others.  `NDSolve` tracks the solution.

```
ClearAll[Isis];
Isis[V_?NumericQ, T1_, T2_, TcAlP_, TcAlI_, 
   gamma1_, gamma2_, Rjunction_] := Re[1/(q Rjunction) NIntegrate[
     SetPrecision[
      ngammaAl[energy - q V, T1, gamma1, TcAlP] ngammaAl[energy, T2, 
        gamma2, TcAlI] (1/(Exp[(energy - q V)/(kB T1)] + 1) - 
         1/(Exp[energy/(kB T2)] + 1)),
      50], {energy, -10 d0max, -ΔAl[T1, TcAlP], ΔAl[T2, TcAlI], ΔAl[T2, 
       TcAlI], ΔAl[T1, TcAlP], 10 d0max}, 
     MinRecursion -> 4, 
     Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "MaxErrorIncreases" -> 100000, 
       "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, "SingularityHandler" -> None}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 5, WorkingPrecision -> 32]];

sol = NDSolve[{Ifix == 
    Isis[V[Temp]/2, 0.2, Temp, 1.5, 1.4, γ0, γ0, 
     RSISIS], x'[Temp] == 1, x[0.2] == 0.2,
   V[0.2] == (VV /. 
      FindRoot[
       Ifix - Isis[VV/2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.5, 1.4, γ0, γ0, 
         RSISIS], {VV, 4.05 d0Al[1.5]/q, 3. d0Al[1.5]/q, 
        4.1 d0Al[1.5]/q}])},
  V,
  {Temp, 0.2, 1.25}]

ListLinePlot[V /. First@sol]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you this is a very good solution! I was using the find root to create a table which I was interpolating to fit some data, is it possible to implement your code to create a function of more variable? I mean now sol=sol[Temp], I would like to create a function like sol=sol[Temp,gamma0,Rsisis...].

Comment: @Giuliano-FrancescoTIMOSSI In theory, yes. In practice, it might be difficult.  Methods for multivariate interpolation and multivariate differential equations (PDEs) are not as robust as single variable methods. I'm fairly confident that if the computations are not numerically ill-conditioned, it can be done in some way, but it might not be a simple adaptation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. We are not use to use the NDSolve and we are wondering about the x variable. Why do you put it there? Sorry. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: @Giuliano-FrancescoTIMOSSI The `x` variable is a dummy variable used to turn your equation into a [DAE system](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDAE.html). `NDSolve` steps `Temp` from `0.2` to `1.25`, integrating `x[Temp]` and using `FindRoot` to solve for `V[Temp]` at each step. It returns the table of values computed in the form of an `InterpolatingFunction`. Is there some reason you're not allowed to use `NDSolve`? Is it a homework problem? The advantage is `NDSolve` automatically figures out the starting point for `FindRoot` at each step.

Comment: I can use it no problem sadly i never follow any course and I was just wondering on how to use the NDsolve in the proper way in the future. NDSolve seams to be much more efficient than my way to proceed.